# Richardson-Lucy not sharpening image

Tags: image-processing

I had posted a question previously about the Richardson-Lucy algorithm.  I have a follow-up question I would appreciate help with.
Below is the Python code I am using.  My input image is already blurry so I removed program lines that I originally had to intentionally blur the image.  I am getting the error "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide relative_blur = image / convolve(im_deconv, psf, mode='same')"  I would appreciate help with debugging this. I kept the lines in the program that I commented out based on the suggestion below.

```
    import numpy as np
    
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
    
    from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2
    
    from skimage import color, data, restoration
    
    Image.open('TOFA-003_UV_Cured_Lincoln_Corrected.bmp').convert('L').save('TOFA-003_UV_Cured_Lincoln_Corrected_gray.bmp')
    
    astro = Image.open('TOFA-003_UV_Cured_Lincoln_Corrected_gray.bmp')
    
    
    psf = np.ones((5, 5)) / 25
    #psf = np.ones((8, 8)) / 25
    
    astro = conv2(astro, psf, 'same')
    astro = astro/255
    # Add Noise to Image
    #astro_noisy = astro.copy()
    #astro_noisy += (np.random.poisson(lam=25, size=astro.shape) - 10) / 255
    
    #astro_noisy = astro_noisy/255
    
    # Restore Image using Richardson-Lucy algorithm
    deconvolved_RL = restoration.richardson_lucy(astro, psf, iterations=2)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 5))
    plt.gray()
    
    for a in (ax[0], ax[1], ax[2]):
           a.axis('off')
    
    ax[0].imshow(astro)
    ax[0].set_title('Original Data')
    
    #ax[1].imshow(astro_noisy)
    #ax[1].set_title('Noisy data')
    
    ax[2].imshow(deconvolved_RL, vmin=astro.min(), vmax=astro.max())
    ax[2].set_title('Restoration using\nRichardson-Lucy')
    
    
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.02, hspace=0.2,
                        top=0.9, bottom=0.05, left=0, right=1)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What does `astro` look like before blurring? Is it actually sharp, or was it already blurry? Note that you do `astro = conv2(astro, psf, 'same')`, so you overwrite the original image, this is why we can’t see it.

Comment: Hello.  I edited my original post with a link to 'Starting image'.  That is the original image.

Comment: That image is already blurry. You blur it with a 5x5 box kernel, which will have very little effect, then you undo that blur. All three images will look very similar because the blur in the original image is stronger than your 5x5 box kernel.

Comment: Hello.  I edited my last post so that I commented out the initial blurring step.